# $f(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$ and $g$ be the inverse of $f$ then find the value of $g'(0)$

I am trying to use $t^2=tan\theta$ but not getting any conclusive result.

Comment: This is an elliptic integral and has no closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$g(f(t))=t:$

$g'(f(t))f'(t)=1;$

For $f'(t)\not = 0:$

$g'(f(t)) = \dfrac{1}{f'(t)}.$

$f(2)=0$; $f'(2)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^4}}.$

Hence?

Answer (score 1):

$g'(0)=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(0))}$. So the answer is $ \sqrt {1+2^{4}}$. The formula for the derivative of an inverse function, namely $(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ can bee found in any text on Calculus. It is proved by applying chain rule to $(f^{-1}\circ f )(x)=x$.