# How to find $g(x)$ here?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, definite-integrals, solution-verification

If $$f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} $$

I have been asked to find $g'(0)$. where $g=f^{-1}$

to do this I attempted to use the definition of an inverse
$$f(g(x))=x$$
so $$f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$$

so $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+g^4(x)}}g'(x)=1$$

which gives us $g'(x)=\sqrt{ 1+g^4(x)}$

beyond this I'm stuck.

could someone guide me on what I could do next?

Comment: Your definition is wrong. It is f(g(x))=x, not f(g(x))=1, unless by $f^{-1}$ you mean $\frac1f$.

Comment: soory, I meant $x$, I'll edit it

Comment: Try the inverse function theorem

Comment: what's that? Never heard of it?

Comment: You aren't asked to find $g'(x)$.  You are asked to find $g'(0)$.  What is $g(0)$?  When is $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: I just looked at the Wikipedia article, I'm afraid it's beyond me, in my classes, we don't use matrices for functional analysis

Comment: @fleablood, I just plugged his into wolfram, I'm getting a complex-valued function, which is why I came here for help

Comment: Strikes me that $g(0) = y$ when $f(y) = 0$ and that only occurs when $y=0$ so $g(0) = 0$ and so $g'(0) = \frac 1{1+0^4} = 1$.  I think.

Comment: @fleablood, jow did you get that last result?

Comment: $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+t^4}} > 0$ so $\int_0^x \frac 1{\sqrt{1+t^4}} dt > 0$ for all $x > 0$ and $f(0)=\int_0^0 \frac 1{\sqrt{1+t^4}} dt = 0$.  $g(x) =w\iff f(w) = x$ so $g(0) =w\iff f(w) =0\iff w=0$ so $g(0) = 0$.  ***YOU*** figured that $g'(x) =\sqrt{1 + g(x)^4}$ so $g'(0) = \sqrt{1 + g(0)^4} = \sqrt{1 + 0^4} = \sqrt 1 = 1$.

Comment: A similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3179225/305862).

Answer (score 1):

Now you have (after the edit(s)) that $\displaystyle f(0)=\int_0^0\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}=0$ so $f^{-1}(0)=g(0)=0$ so $g’(0)=\sqrt{1+(g(0))^4}=1.$

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't give me $g'(x)$, which is what I need to find

Comment: I am quoting you:  "I have been asked to find g′(0). "... You said that!.....  You do *NOT* need to find $g'(x)$.  You were never asked to find $g'(x)$.  You were asked to find $g'(0)$ and this gives you exactly that.

Comment: You have been asked $g’(\mathbf{0})$, not $g’(\mathbf{x})$, because the examiner wants to probably test the insight that g(0)=0.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, I see, thanks

Comment: @fleablood, yeah, got it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

From what you have, $g'(0) = \sqrt{1+g^4(0)}$.

Now, $g(0) = f^{-1}(0)$, and by definition, $f(g(0)) = 0$. Note that $f(x) = 0$ only when $x=0$ since the integrated function is strictly positive. Hence, $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x)=\int_0^{x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$, So by Lebnitz we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$

Let $y=f(x)\implies x=f^{-1} (y)=g(y).$

Start with $f(g(x))=x$ or $g(f(x))=x$

D.w.r.t. $x$ to get $g'(f(x)) f'(x)=1 \implies g'(y_0)=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$
Where $(x_0,y_0)$ falls on the curve $y=f(x)$. Here, we have $x_0=0=y_0$, then
$$g'(0)=\frac{1}{f'(0)}=1$$

One may also write $$\frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dy}|_{y=y_0}=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$$

Comment: Yes, just edited it.

Comment: You may see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do next. Let $x=0$ in
$$f'(g(x))g'(x)=1.$$
Then you have
$$ f'(g(0))g'(0)=1. $$
Noting $g(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\bigg|_{x=0}=1$,
you have
$$ g'(0)=1. $$